# AspectJ - Why cflow leads to an infinite recursion when it is not combined with an && (aspectJ intersection)?

Tags: recursion, stack-overflow, aop, aspectj

I have a question about **cflow** or **cflowbelow** in AspectJ.

> ***cflow(Pointcut)***
>
> Picks out all join points in the control flow of the
>   join points picked out by the pointcut, including pointcut's join
>   points themselves.
>
> ***cflowbelow(Pointcut)***
>
> Picks out all join points in the control flow
>   below the join points picked out by the pointcut.

For both, I could find only the definition and that:

> When defining pointcut using *cflow* or *cflowbelow*, we need to ensure
>   that the pointcut **does not capture the calls that are made from the
>   same aspect**, otherwise it will invoke *recursive method calls* and we
>   will get **StackOverflowError**.
>
> This happens because *cflow()* will also
>   capture the method calls from the aspect itself and try to apply the
>   advice to it. This can be avoided by using within() construct.
>   *within()* takes a type(class or interface) name as argument and
>   captures all join points the are defined in that type.

But no explanation about how actually cflow() or cflowbelow() lead to an infinite recursion when they are used without *within* or together with an && expression like:

```
pointcut aPointcut(): execution(void Test.foo()) && !cflowbelow(execution(void Test.foo()));
```

Which will match e.g. the first execution of `Test.foo()` only ignoring any bubbling if inside `Test.foo()` another call to `Test.foo()` is made or a call to a `foo()` method of a class which extends `Test` is made.

My question is: why cflow actually leads to an infinite recursion when it is used e.g. without within? How does the weaving with cflow happens so that it leads to such a recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void sayHelloTo(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name + "!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sayHelloTo("world");
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Application;

public aspect CflowRecursionDemo {
    // Attention, StackOverflowError!
    /*
    before() : cflow(execution(* Application.sayHelloTo(..))) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
    */

    before() : !within(CflowRecursionDemo) && cflow(execution(* Application.sayHelloTo(..))) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

The commented-out advice leads to a `StackOverflowError` while the active one does not.

**Console output:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.sayHelloTo(String))
get(PrintStream java.lang.System.out)
call(java.lang.StringBuilder(String))
call(StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(String))
call(StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(String))
call(String java.lang.StringBuilder.toString())
call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(String))
Hello world!
```

Explanation: As you can see there are a number of joinpoints within the control flow of the active advice. Each one of these would again trigger the active advice because each of them again matches the pointcut `cflow(execution(* Application.sayHelloTo(..)))`. The advice is a method like any other, though, it just happens to be inside of an aspect. Anyway, it is in the control flow of its own pointcut which again triggers the advice which again is in its own pointcut's control flow and so forth. Infinite recursion!